# Creating windows forms application in C++ (w/o .NET)

Tags: c++, winforms

I would like to create a windows forms application in C++, but I don't want to use .NET framework.
I also don't want to code everything from scratch. I'd like to have a toolbox such as the one in Visual Studio. Could you recommend some editor/compiler for this task?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are your reasons for not wanting to use .NET???
If I would start from scratch I would use .net over MFC and others unless I had very specific reasons to do so.

Comment: I developed an application in C# 4.0. I think it's the best programming language ever. However, the users are having trouble to install the .net 4.0 runtime on their machine since they are using very very old computer, their windows is not up to date, etc. That's why I would like to rewrite the application in C++ and to see how it works.

Comment: Wow, that is customer service ;-)
Just be warned that MFC is VERY different than win forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look up [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) or the [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com/). both have a nice GUI editor and  integrate with visual studio (MFC actually comes with visual studio)
Winforms is a strictly .NET thing so whatever you do, it won't be Winforms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I choose to use the MFC 10, will the end user need to install the .NET 4.0 runtime on his machine?

Comment: MFC is native library and you dont need to install .Net 4.0 , but you need to deploy MFC dll if you link dynamically  with MFC.

Comment: @sljaker: No, you will not need the .NET Framework at all if you use MFC. As long as you don't create a C++/CLI project in Visual C++, you will be free of .NET forever. You *will* have a dependence on the MFC libraries, however. You have a choice of either linking dynamically, which will require you to install the appropriate version of MFC on the users' computers, or you can link *statically*, which will increase the size of your executable somewhat, but eliminate dependencies altogether.

Comment: @sljaker: Honestly, if your users' computers are "so old" that they can't install .NET 4.0, they're probably too old to use any recent version of MFC. The last version of VS that can compile programs to run on Windows 2000 is VS 2008, and that doesn't target anything older either. You're going to feel like you've taken a pretty big step backwards with MFC, and you'll have to re-learn C++ as an entirely new language. The best thing to do is to write a native Win32 application without using any GUI frameworks at all, but this is a *huge* undertaking and I don't recommend it at all.

Answer (score 0):

in the C++ world many frameworks to develop GUI layer exist,and if your application must be cross platform the popular choice could be  [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/),and I suggest you Qt.

If you are Pro Microsoft you have [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/) and MFC and I suggest you WTL.